# How do you change a boolean value if a user clicks login button in a different page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change the user value to true when a user clicks a login button in my login page. I'm a beginner level web dev student and I am still learning how to use useState in React. I am sorry for this dumb question but please help! Thank you so much!!!!

> TopBar.jsx

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import './topbar.css';

export default function topbar() {
  const user = false;

  return (
    <div className='top'>
      <div className='topLeft'>
        <i className='topIcon fab fa-facebook-square'></i>
        <i className='topIcon fab fa-twitter-square'></i>
        <i className='topIcon fab fa-pinterest-square'></i>
        <i className='topIcon fab fa-instagram-square'></i>
    </div>
    <div className='topCenter'>
      <ul className='topList'>
        <li className='topListItem'>
          <Link className='link' to ='/'>HOME</Link>
        </li>
        <li className='topListItem'><Link className='link' to ='/'>ABOUT</Link></li>
        <li className='topListItem'><Link className='link' to ='/'>CONTACT</Link></li>
        <li className='topListItem'><Link className='link' to ='/write'>WRITE</Link></li>
        <li className='topListItem'>{user && 'LOGOUT'}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div className='topRight'>
      {
        user ? (
          <Link className='link' to ='/settings'>
            <img 
              className='topImg' 
              src="https://organicthemes.com/demo/profile/files/2018/05/profile-pic.jpg" 
              alt="" 
            />
          </Link>
        ) : (
          <ul className='topList'>
            <li className='topListItem'>
              <Link className='link' to ='/login'>LOGIN</Link>
            </li>
            <li className='topListItem'>
              <Link className='link' to ='/register'>REGISTER</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        )
      }
      <i className='topSearchIcon fas fa-search'></i>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> Login.jsx

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import './login.css'

export default function Login() {
  return (
    <div className='login'>
      <span className="LoginTitle">Login</span>
      <form className="loginForm">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" className='loginInput' placeholder='Enter your email...' />
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" className='loginInput' placeholder='Enter your password...' />
        <button className="loginButton">Login</button>
      </form>
      <button className="loginRegisterButton">
        <Link className='link' to='/register'>Register</Link>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I have know idea why are you solving this way. But to be reactive you should store that user in state.
E.g

```js
import {useState} from 'react';

const [user, setUser] = useState(false);

return (
<button onClick={() => setUser(true)}>Click me!</button>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you write your own server script? You need to send a HTTPS POST request to the server and validate the login data. Look into [React-Router](https://reactrouter.com/), [Express](https://expressjs.com/), or [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) to learn about server-side routing.

Here's a beginner friendly [article about POST requests](https://strdoc.com/get-vs-post-which-one-more-secure/)